# video conference in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, video, video-conferencing, conference

I want to develop a web application (asp.net) to make interviews through video conference. So I need to find a control that could be embedded into the webform.

Do you know any control that allows this functionality and also allows to save the video/audio?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Silverlight can easily do this within a .net page.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be a web application?  check out this project someone created.  Seems like it will get you going in the right direction.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Video_Voice_Conferencing.aspx